# How to determine the optimal sort_buffer_size?

Tags: mysql, myisam, mariadb, tuning, sorting

I read from a sample configuration file which says the following:

```
# Sort buffer is used to perform sorts for some ORDER BY and GROUP BY
# queries. If sorted data does not fit into the sort buffer, a disk
# based merge sort is used instead - See the "Sort_merge_passes"
# status variable. Allocated per thread if sort is needed.
```

I have a couple of queries which use filesort. How do I determine what is the size of the buffer I need for queries to run smoothly without hitting the disk?

Comment: Have you run [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) or [tuning-primer](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) You may see something interesting about your my.cnf in these apps.

Answer (score 26):

There is only one status variable that cares about [**sort_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size). That's what you have in the message back in the question : [**Sort_merge_passes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Sort_merge_passes). The MySQL Documentation says:

> Sort_merge_passes : The number of merge passes that the sort algorithm has had to do. If this value is large, you should consider increasing the value of the [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) system variable.

Please keep in mind one thing about [**sort_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)

> If you see many Sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output, you can consider increasing the sort_buffer_size value to speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with query optimization or improved indexing

While raising `sort_buffer_size` can help queries with `GROUP BY`s and `ORDER BY`s, you are better off improving the queries that you can improve and adding indexes that can be used by the Query Optimizer.

Question remains: How do you check the [**Sort_merge_passes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Sort_merge_passes) ???

Use this code, to check how many Sort_merge_passes happened in the last 5 minutes. It also computes the Sort_merge_passes per hour.

```
SET @SleepTime = 300;
SELECT variable_value INTO @SMP1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name = 'Sort_merge_passes';
SELECT SLEEP(@SleepTime) INTO @x;
SELECT variable_value INTO @SMP2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name = 'Sort_merge_passes';
SET @SMP = @SMP2 - @SMP1;
SET @SMP_RATE = @SMP * 3600 / @SleepTime;
SELECT @SMP,@SMP_RATE;
```

If you find the Sort_merge_passes and the rate too high, then feel free to increase [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size). Suppose you want to raise to 4M. You would run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
```

You would then add this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 4M
```

You would run the code periodically to check for other times [**Sort_merge_passes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Sort_merge_passes) spikes.

Comment: This is the much better answer

Comment: @RolanoMySQLDBA can you define "many" in the following :  "If you see many Sort_merge_passes per second"

Comment: What is considered large for `Sort_merge_passes`? 20, 200, 2000 ?

Comment: the script you provided just goes to sleep and never returns , i wonder what is wrong here.

Comment: At Oracle the recommended threshold for Sort_merge_passes is < 10 per second.  The formula is Sort_merge_passes / Uptime.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to change the sort_buffer_size from default. You misunderstand it's use based on the question. You should begin by examining the SQL to see if you are able to tune it and satisfy ORDER BY/GROUP BY conditions using an index. It will generally be a composite index.

Further:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/05/09/how-to-tune-mysqls-sort_buffer_size/

Comment: Sorry to say that I find that post hardly useful. It is like telling people not to do something just because you are not an expert. As pointed out by the first commentator, the sample `.cnf` files shipped with mysql do not use the default setting.

Comment: If you read it again it also says that the expert already knows not to change the value from default. The sample .cnf files should not be used or referenced as good practice. If you need help building a my.cnf file Percona offer a fairly thorough wizard. https://tools.percona.com/wizard

Answer (score 2):

The guidance in the manual (5.0-5.5) is

> If you see many Sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
>   output, you can consider increasing the sort_buffer_size value to
>   speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with
>   query optimization or improved indexing. The entire buffer is
>   allocated even if it is not all needed, so setting it larger than
>   required globally will slow down most queries that sort. It is best to
>   increase it as a session setting, and only for the sessions that need
>   a larger size. On Linux, there are thresholds of 256KB and 2MB where
>   larger values may significantly slow down memory allocation, so you
>   should consider staying below one of those values. Experiment to find
>   the best value for your workload.

From 5.6 onwards the wording indicates that the optimizer can pick a value for a query and that the server can extend the buffer up to the limit. This mitigates the cost of setting the value too high. So it sounds like you may want to be conservative, lower than then default (As the release cnf files do) for releases under 5.6.4 but can afford to have a higher limit of say the default 2MB, or even more, from 5.6.4 as the full amount is not blindly allocated.

> As of MySQL 5.6.4, the optimizer tries to work out how much space is
>   needed but can allocate more, up to the limit.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine the optimal `sort_buffer_size` is to benchmark it.

How? Like @RolandoMySQLDBA said checking `Sort_merge_passes` might be helpful, but that's not the only factor that affects the performance.
You should be careful when you increase the `sort_buffer_size`.

[The document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) says that

> On Linux, there are thresholds of 256KB and 2MB where larger values may significantly slow down memory allocation, so you should consider staying below one of those values.

There's [a post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/18/how-fast-can-you-sort-data-with-mysql/) about the testing which concludes that

> `sort_merge_passes` are not that bad. Setting your `sort_buffer_size` large enough so there is zero `sort_merge_passes` may not be optimal.

When I tested, I also get a similar result.

Ideally, it would be best to avoid the situation that you need to optimize the `sort_buffer_size`. How? [This ORDER BY Optimization document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) might help you to understand how things work under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

"mysql> SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 4;"
its a bad way to put in 4m the sort buffer size,  thats makes sort buffer size have 4GB
use

"mysql> SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 4;"

If i'm been your, i don't try to change short buffer size, that is a good way to make crash your server, and send to trash performance.
It's better try to make better querys.

Comment: How can any large sorting happen in a 4K sort buffer ? Note that you said `1024 * 4`. That's 4096, 4K.

Comment: What Rolando said ^^. And the minimum allowed value is 32K.