# MySQL "Out of sort memory" error on a simple GROUP_CONCAT query

Tags: mysql, group-by, concat, group-concatenation, substring

I have a (what it seems to me) simple query which fails to run on a simple table, the error is:

```
Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
```

These are the SQL statements which I'm trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)

)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=11 CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';

INSERT INTO `permissions` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  (1,'ocjena_dobavljaca.view'),
  (2,'ocjena_dobavljaca.edit'),
  (3,'ocjena_dobavljaca.delete'),
  (4,'zaposlenici.view'),
  (5,'zaposlenici.edit'),
  (6,'zaposlenici.delete'),
  (7,'vatrogasni_aparati.view'),
  (8,'vatrogasni_aparati.edit'),
  (9,'vatrogasni_aparati.delete'),
  (10,'organizacijska_shema_drustva');
COMMIT;

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '.', 1) as n, 
    COUNT(*) as num,
    GROUP_CONCAT(name)as nn
FROM permissions
GROUP BY n
```

You can check it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91f48b/7).

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68443/29032) states:

> While raising sort_buffer_size can help queries queries with GROUP BYs and ORDER BYs, you are better off improving the queries that you can improve and adding indexes that can be used by the Query Optimizer.

but I don't see any way to improve the query or add indexes to the table, as they are quite simple.

Increasing the `sort_buffer_size` from 64K (default) to 256K solves the issue, but I'm not sure if this is the right solution.
The other solution is to make the query with a subquery (two `SELECT`s), which seems a bit redundant:

```
SELECT 
  n,
  COUNT(*) as num,
  GROUP_CONCAT(name)as nn
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '.', 1) as n, 
        name 
    FROM permissions) a
GROUP BY n;
```

Can anyone explain why the error?

Comment: Get rid of UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), -- It is redundant because the PK is a UNIQUE key.

Comment: @RickJames The DDL was automatically generated by a gui app

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your name column concatenates two items.  Try building the table with the column split.

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `permission` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `object_permission` (`object`, `permission`)
d
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=11 CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';

INSERT INTO `permissions` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  (1,'ocjena_dobavljaca','view'),
  (2,'ocjena_dobavljaca','edit'),
  (3,'ocjena_dobavljaca','delete'),
  (4,'zaposlenici','view'),
  (5,'zaposlenici','edit'),
  (6,'zaposlenici','delete'),
  (7,'vatrogasni_aparati','view'),
  (8,'vatrogasni_aparati','edit'),
  (9,'vatrogasni_aparati','delete'),
  (10,'organizacijska_shema_drustva','');
COMMIT;

SELECT 
    object, 
    COUNT(*) as num,
    GROUP_CONCAT(permission)as nn
FROM permissions
GROUP BY object;
```

Comment: I mentioned in my questions that I'm aware of other solutions (splitting the column or moving the `object` to a different table is one of them), but I wanted to avoid complicating a seemingly simple query.  And **I wanted to learn** why this error happens.

Comment: @ekstrakt When you generate queries that are edge cases, as you have done, you can get strange results. To determine what actually is occurring you would need to examine the code or step through it with a debugger.   I suspect you are getting some large buffers or join sets for each record in the original query.   An explain plan may provide some initial insights.